# Grub Boot Loader Issue

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 22.04

I installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 as dual boot alongside Windows 11. After the installation when I restarted the laptop it entered into grub loader and I logged in to the ubuntu. Later when I restarted again it directly goes to the windows and not showing the grub loader. Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: both Ubuntu/grub and Windows with updates will reset UEFI boot order to be first in boot order. Check UEFI settings (settings, not UEFI boot menu) and change boot order. What brand/model system? If you need details, it varies by brand.